# Is it possible to disable Google Play apps remote installation?

Tags: google

I would like to know if it's possible on a given device to disable the Google Play 'feature' to remotely install an app into it, once logged in from a [browser](http://techcrunch.com/2012/06/27/googles-play-store-now-lets-users-remotely-update-and-uninstall-android-apps/).
I'm not interested in workarounds on how to prevent it (like installing a 3rd party app), I'm interested in disabling it, so I want to log into the Google Play in any browser, and either not to find a given device in the list of devices, or not to see the Install button at all.
My concern is about security, and any helpful answer is welcome! I googled already and couldn't find much info.

[image: install app from browser]

Comment: Afraid that's not possible – but am open to learn otherwise. For your concern about security: to remotely install apps that way, a person must have access to your account (and then, with physical access to your device, could install apps anyway; yes, I'm aware that "physical access" is a limiting factor here). So 1st security measure is keeping that from happening by keeping your credentials safe – and lock your computer/browser when logged-in or log-out when leaving it alone.

Comment: I did not tried it myself, but what if Google Play app on device is DISABLED? AFAIK web interface must be using some kind of PUSH Mechanism to talk with Google play app on device for app installation  and if at that moment if Google play app is Disabled, it may not be able to HANDLE this notification and thus no installation. This is my guess...did not tried it.

Comment: @Izzy a person (or bot) whom will accidentally guess my Google Account password (which of course is long and unique and contains numbers and symbols etc etc) would be able to remotely install apps on my phone: this is the concern I have, since from there she could - at least theoretically - send an sms to start up the newly installed app (say a vpn for instance), at least on some Android versions, then ssh to the device and gain root access. At that point, well, you guess it :)
So even if my credentials are safe, I don't like the purely theoretical possibility of it to happen.

Comment: @AADTechnical that's an intriguing and interesting idea, thank you! I haven't tried as well, but it's not suitable for me to completely disable the Google Play app on each device, as that will exclude also all the continuous updates of the apps.

Comment: @AADTechnical is indeed correct with the push service (that's how it works). And btw that can be a life-saver in some situations (e.g. having deleted your only launcher, you can push a launcher this way to get your device working again). The "guessing of credentials", while not impossible, is rather unlikely – given a good and strong password.